# send custom field from purchase order to receipt (stock) in odoo12

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

i have a custom field in purchase order (order_line),
when i click on the confirm button that that field should pass to the receipt in stock along with all product information.
how can i achieve this, like in sales we have **_prepare_procurement_values** method.
so here which method is available?

```
def _prepare_account_move_line(self, move):
    res = super(InheritPurchaseOrder, self)._prepare_account_move_line(move)
    #mycode
    return res
```

i have tried this but got no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

milan vala

Use this method `_prepare_stock_moves` to pass the value from order line to `stock.move`.

Thanks